# Convert currency formatted string to normal string

Tags: objective-c, currency

I have one string with a currency symbol and currency formatted…
I want to convert it into normal string..

My Code is like this..

```
-(NSString *)removeCurrency:(NSString *)str{


    NSNumberFormatter *_currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [_currencyFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"-¤#,##0.00"];

    NSLog(@"\n With Currency : %@",str);
    NSLog(@"\n Without Currency : %@",[_currencyFormatter numberFromString:str]);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_currencyFormatter numberFromString:str]]; 
}
```

But problem is there when I enter the string Rs 0.009 it return me different values but with another number it works perfect …

Comment: Check the answers for [this question][1], I hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156347/cocoa-nsnumberformattercurrencystyle-without-return-zero

Comment: Can you provide more details, like how this method is being called and what the actual values of str are being passed in?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store the value before you added the currency formatting to it.  Typically you only add the currency formatting before you display, and not for storage.

Answer (score 1):

if you set currency as per locale than you can remove symbol using current locale and get string

```
-(NSString *)removeCurrency:(NSString *)str{

    NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *currency = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
    NSNumberFormatter *_currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *currencyCode=[currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
    [_currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    [_currencyFormatter setCurrencyCode:currencyCode];
    [_currencyFormatter setLenient:YES];
    [_currencyFormatter setCurrencySymbol:currency];

    NSLog(@"\n Currency : %@",currency);
    NSLog(@"\n Without Currency : %@",[_currencyFormatter numberFromString:str]);
    NSLog(@"\n Without Currency : %f",[[_currencyFormatter numberFromString:str] floatValue]);
  //  NSLog(@"\n Without Currency : %.03f",[[_currencyFormatter numberFromString:currency]]);

    NSLog(@"\n With Currency : %@",str);
    NSLog(@"\n Without Currency : %@",[_currencyFormatter numberFromString:str]);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_currencyFormatter numberFromString:str]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just keep it simple.

```
    NSString *stringWithoutCurrency = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$"   withString:@""];
```

From what I can tell, there is no equivalent NSNumberFormatter for NSString's, however I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You say that with "Rs 0.009" you get a different value. Is that value 0.008999999999999999, by any chance? If it is, you are actually getting the correct result. Chalk it up to floating-point inaccuracy.

Here is some code that shows this:

```
NSString* str = @"Rs 0.009";

NSNumberFormatter *_currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[_currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[_currencyFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"INR"];
[_currencyFormatter setLenient:YES];
[_currencyFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@"Rs"];

NSLog(@"\n With Currency : %@",str);
NSLog(@"\n Without Currency : %@",[_currencyFormatter numberFromString:str]);
NSLog(@"\n Without Currency : %f",[[_currencyFormatter numberFromString:str] floatValue]);
NSLog(@"\n Without Currency : %.03f",[[_currencyFormatter numberFromString:str] floatValue]);
```